# Memory bloat while rendering 50 rows of data in a v-data-table using vue-infinite-loader

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, infinite-scroll

I'm having an issue with memory bloat when using [vue-infinite-loading](https://github.com/PeachScript/vue-infinite-loading/tree/master/docs)  and/or the v-data-table that is being used to render the table data. in the .vue file. I'm trying to understand why fetching 50 rows of data, when the infinite loader is triggered, which is about 100KB in size, results in Chrome and IE increasing about 30MB!!!

Each time the infinite loader gets triggered at the bottom of the page it fetches the data (50 rows with about 6 columns of simple data), I receive then push the data to the array "list" in the ajax response, the vue infinite loader then renders (concats) it at the bottom of the v-data-table table.

But every time I do a new fetch the amount of memory that gets consumed by IE and Chrome is like 30+ MB. So after just a couple of fetches, the memory gets bloated and bogs down the machine. Even though the amount of data being fetched is about 100KB.

I fetch 100kb worth of data, which is 50 rows. When I receive the data I push it into a list like this

```js
this.list.push(...response.data)

//tried with same memory bloat issue
//this.list = this.list.concat(response.data)

// tried with same memory bloat issue
//this.list = [].concat(this.list, response.data);
```

Where data is a simple object with about 6 properties that are ints and strings

```
public class GetRecordsReturnViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public string StartDateString { get; set; }
    public string EndDateString { get; set; }
    public string WitnessName { get; set; }
    public string SourceCode { get; set; }
    public string JobsiteName { get; set; }
    public string ShipName { get; set; }
    public string EmployerCode { get; set; }

}
```

and list is an array of those objects.

```js
list: {
  get() {
    return this.$store.state.records.list
  },
  set(value) {
    this.$store.commit('records/listUpdate', value)
  }
},
```

and the mutation and component is this below in the index.js file

```js
const records = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    list: [],
    // other suff
  },
  mutations: {
    listUpdate(state, value) {
      state.list = value
    },
    // other stuff
  },
}
```

My vue file has this in it to display the html for the table when infinite loading

```html
<div class="results-table-wrapper">
  <v-data-table style="" class="max-height-scrollable" :headers="listHeaders" :items="list" :pagination.sync="pagination" hide-actions>

    <template slot="headerCell" slot-scope="props">
                    <span @click="resetForSort(props.header)">{{ props.header.text }}</span>
                </template>

    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">

                    <tr>

                        <td style="cursor: pointer; color: #1976d2;" @click="routeToListItem(props.item.id)"><span>{{ props.item.id }}</span></td>

                        <td><span>{{ props.item.witnessName }}</span></td>
                        <td><span>{{ props.item.sourceCode }}</span></td>

                        <td><span>{{ props.item.startDateString }}</span></td>
                        <td><span>{{ props.item.endDateString }}</span></td>

                        <td>
                            <span >{{ props.item.jobsiteName }}</span>
                            <span ><br /></span>
                            <span >{{ props.item.shipName }}</span>
                        </td>

                        <td><span>{{ props.item.employerCode }}</span></td>

                    </tr>
                </template>

    <template slot="no-data">
                    <p class="text-xs-center" v-show="!listHasItems">Use at least 1 filter and press the search button.</p>
                </template>
  </v-data-table>
</div>
<infinite-loading @infinite="infiniteHandler" ref="infiniteLoading" v-show="showList == true">
  <span slot="no-results">
                No records found.
            </span>
  <span slot="no-more">
                No more records.
            </span>
  <span slot="spinner">
                <font-awesome-icon icon="circle-notch" spin />
            </span>
</infinite-loading>​
```